# Any inner product space $V$ is a normed space with norm $||f||=\sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> (1) Show that any inner product space $V$ is a normed space with norm
>   $||f||=\sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle}$, $\forall f\in V$.

Can someone please explain what kind of proof is required here? I've seen something like:

> (2) If $X$ is a linear space with inner product $(.,.)$, then we can
>   define a norm on $X$ by $||x|| = \sqrt{(x,x)}$. Thus, any inner
>   product space is a normed linear space.

Where is the "proof" here? It seems like it is saying the same thing as $(1)$, so what is required of a proof to show the result of $(1)$?

Comment: Were you given the [norm axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition) that any norm must satisfy?

Comment: @JohnD Yes, I was.

Comment: @CalebJ Do you understand what's being asked of you in the first question?

Comment: @CalebJ: I see you have 7 questions but no accepted answers. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the norm axioms, verify that they each hold:

1. $\|c \mathbf{x}\|=|c|\|\mathbf{x}\|$ for all scalars $c$ and vectors $\mathbf x$
2. $\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|\le\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|$ for all vectors $\mathbf x, \mathbf y$
3. $\|\mathbf x\|\ge 0$ with equality if and only if $\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$.

Just do this using $\|\mathbf x\|:=\sqrt{\langle\mathbf x,\mathbf x\rangle}$ with the scalars $c$ from whatever your underlying field is (probably $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$).

Comment: Can you please do one of these as an example?

Comment: Fall back on the [properties of the underlying inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition): $\|cx\|=\sqrt{\langle cx,cx\rangle}=\sqrt{c^2\langle x, x\rangle}=\sqrt{c^2}\,\sqrt{\langle x,x,\rangle}=|c|\|x\|$

Comment: The other two are similar. The key is you will need to use your knowledge of the inner product axioms along the way for each of the three parts.

Answer (score 1):

The last condition to show that $|x| = \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$ is  a norm (the other two are quite simple) should go like this:

$$\begin{align}|x+y|^2 &= \langle x+y,x+y\rangle = |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2\langle x,y\rangle \\ &\leq |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2| x| \dot  \ |y| = (|x|+|y|)^2\end{align} $$

The question says that from an inner product, we may define the norm of a vector $x \in E$ by taking $|x|  = \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle} $. Not every normed space $E$, however, comes from an inner product. This will only occur when the so called [Parallelogram Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) holds:

$$|x+y|^2 + |x-y|^2 = 2(|x|+|y|)^2$$

For example the norm $|x|' = \sum |x_i| $ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not yielded from an inner product because the Parallelogram Law does not hold.

If you have any question don't hesitate to ask on the comments.